# how to pass string with quotation marks to a oracle procedure

Tags: php

i have a variable that receive the string like this:

`'BA','RJ','SC'`

and i need to send to db in this format as a string, but i'm getting the error:

> **PLS-00103:** Encountered the symbol "BA" when expecting one of the following: ) , * & | = - +

i print the $sql to see how the values are going to:

`BEGIN TWD_WEB_CRM.PESQUISA_CLIENTES(1,''BA','RJ','SC'','132','',:status,:refc); END;`

so, this is how i'm passing with php to the procedure:

`$sql = "BEGIN TWD_WEB_CRM.PESQUISA_CLIENTES(".$codemp.",'".$estados."','".$diac."','".$dian."',:status,:refc); END;";`

the variable `$estados` receive: `'BA','RJ','SC'`

so, my question is:

how can i pass this kind of string with `'` and `,` to my procedure using php ?

i try with `\`  but didin't work.

what i'm missing ?

any question, by my guest.

Thanks.

**Edit**

```
  BEGIN TWD_WEB_CRM.PESQUISA_CLIENTES
  (

      1,
      ''BA','RJ','SC'',  // this supposed to be 1 field with strings...
      '132',
      '',
      :status,
      :refc
  ); 
  END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, escape single quotes by doubling them. This will treat the full comma-separated string as one string literal with escaped quotes.

```
''BA'',''RJ'',''SC''
```

This assumes I understand correctly and you are passing these values as a string literal.

Ultimately, your query should look like:\

```
BEGIN TWD_WEB_CRM.PESQUISA_CLIENTES
  (

      1,
      '''BA'',''RJ'',''SC''',  // <-- Doubled quotes inside the quoted string.
      '132',
      '',
      :status,
      :refc
  ); 
  END;
```

Comment: the problem is,  `$estados` , because the format with `,` and `´` he interprete as a saparated values, but its supposed to be one thing. like `BEGIN TWD_WEB_CRM.PESQUISA_CLIENTES(1,"'BA','RJ','SC'",'132','',:status,:refc); END;` , the 'BA','RJ','SC' is one thing.

Comment: @RicardoArruda If it is supposed to be one string, try doubling the quotes as I have above.

Comment: @RicardoArruda Yes. You could use `str_replace("'", "''", $string)` to double the quotes.